# Testing javascript functions across page load

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, end-to-end

I have a code that works with state. On every state change the current state is saved to sessionStorage and when user comes to different page that state is loaded back from sessionStorage.

I want to test that state is properly saved to storage and on page load is properly loaded back. But I don't know how to test this scenario.

I'm currently using Mocha, but I know only how to write unit tests in it.

Comment: I think the answer on this other question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689110/full-integration-testing-for-nodejs-and-the-client-side-with-yeoman-and-mocha

Mocha itself is not enough to cover this kind of integration testing, the other option is to make unit testing and mock session storage, but it seems you want to make some kind of integration testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocha itself is not enough to acchieve this, you need a tool to allow you do this end-to-end

I was testing a marvelous thing named **phantomjs** (http://phantomjs.org/ ), you can do something like this:

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var page = webpage.create();
page.open('http://www.google.com', function() {
  window.localStorage.setItem("test", "xtest");
  console.log(window.localStorage);

  page = webpage.create();
  page.open('http://www.google.com', function() {
    console.log(
        window.localStorage.getItem("test")
        ); // xtest
    console.log(window.localStorage);
    phantom.exit();
  });
});
```

You also need node-phantom (https://www.npmjs.org/package/phantom) to allow you using both mocha and phantomjs from the same node.js script to write your tests